# echo data through ajax function to a table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I am trying to use the ajax function to echo out the data submitted to a table. But it did not turn out the way i wanted it to be. The values became a string of values which i do not want that to happen, i want the value to be in a table form.

Below is my code for the form,

```html
<div id="formbox">
  <form id="formTable">

    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Start Time</th>
          <th>End Time</th>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <th>Wednesday</th>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <th>Saturday</th>
          <th>Sunday</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime" id="starttime" width="50px">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endtime">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Monday" value="1" id="monday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday" value="1" id="tuesday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday" value="1" id="wednesday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Thursday" value="1" id="thursday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Friday" value="1" id="friday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Saturday" value="1" id="saturday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sunday" value="1" id="sunday">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" id="send">
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </form>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div id="comment"></div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript code,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function showComment() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "registerarray.php",
        data: "action=showcomment",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#comment").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    showComment();

    $("#send").click(function() {

      var starttime = $("#starttime").val();
      var endtime = $("#endtime").val();

      if (document.getElementById('monday').checked) {
        var monday = $("#monday").val();
      }
      if (document.getElementById('tuesday').checked) {
        var tuesday = $("#tuesday").val();
      }
      if (document.getElementById('wednesday').checked) {
        var wednesday = $("#wednesday").val();
      }
      if (document.getElementById('thursday').checked) {
        var thursday = $("#thursday").val();
      }
      if (document.getElementById('friday').checked) {
        var friday = $("#friday").val();
      }
      if (document.getElementById('saturday').checked) {
        var saturday = $("#saturday").val();
      }
      if (document.getElementById('sunday').checked) {
        var sunday = $("#sunday").val();
      }



      var dataString = "starttime1=" + starttime + "&endtime1=" + endtime + "&monday1=" + monday + "&tuesday1=" + tuesday + "&wednesday1=" + wednesday + "&thursday1=" + thursday + "&friday1=" + friday + "&saturday1=" + saturday + "&sunday1=" + sunday + "&action=addcomment";

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "registerarray.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          showComment();
          $("#formTable")[0].reset();

        }

      });

    });
  });
```

My register array codes, to register and to echo the data from the database,

```
<?php

$action = $_POST["action"];

if ($action == "showcomment") {

    require_once 'dbfunction.php';
    $con = getDbConnect();

    if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        $show = "SELECT * FROM scheduletime";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $show);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["startTime"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["endTime"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Monday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Tuesday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Wednesday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Thursday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Friday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Saturday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . $row["Sunday"] . "</th>";
            echo "<th></th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    ?>


    <?php

} else if ($action == "addcomment") {
    require_once 'dbfunction.php';
    $con = getDbConnect();

    $starttime2 = $_POST['starttime1'];
    $endtime2 = $_POST['endtime1'];
    $monday2 = $_POST['monday1'];
    $tuesday2 = $_POST['tuesday1'];
    $wednesday2 = $_POST['wednesday1'];
    $thursday2 = $_POST['thursday1'];
    $friday2 = $_POST['friday1'];
    $saturday2 = $_POST['saturday1'];
    $sunday2 = $_POST['sunday1'];

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO scheduletime (startTime, endTime, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)" .
                "VALUES ('$starttime2', '$endtime2', '$monday2', '$tuesday2', '$wednesday2', '$thursday2', '$friday2', '$saturday2', '$sunday2')";

        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }
    echo "Your comment has been sent";
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

The current out put that i receive is a long string of data linked together and not imputed into the table.

I would want the string of values to be inserted into the table accordingly.

Comment: you are using this: `$("#comment").html(data);` but I do not see `#comment` anywhere in your view html. Am i missing something?

Comment: And what's the result of $("#comment").html(data)? What is happened with your table after it?

Comment: @CodeGodie I just updated my code, i added in the #comment part

Comment: got it , see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing out your results per every iteration of your `while` loop, you need to create a string that hold the html table you are trying to pass. To do this, change this:

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["startTime"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["endTime"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Monday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Tuesday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Wednesday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Thursday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Friday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Saturday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["Sunday"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

to this:

```
   $html = "";
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $r =  "<tr>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["startTime"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["endTime"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Monday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Tuesday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Wednesday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Thursday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Friday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Saturday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td>" . $row["Sunday"] . "</td>";
        $r .=  "<td></td>";
        $r .=  "</tr>";
        $html .= $r;
    }
    echo $html;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I see now that you provided the code that shows `#comment`. The problem is that you are using a `div` inside a `table` You need to change that because your browser will place any `div` outside of the table unless the `div` resides in `<td>` tags. Remove that div, and add the id to the `tbody` instead.

Change this:

```
<tbody>
  <div id="comment"></div>
</tbody>
```

to this:

```
<tbody id="comment">
</tbody>
```

Comment: I gotten the same result

Comment: what result are you getting? can you provide the results?

Comment: All the values appeared as one row of data linked together

Comment: Now the values appeared in the table, but all values are squeezed into one row one column.

Comment: also check out the `while` loop in my answer. I made some edits.

Comment: Same output, the data appeared as one row of data squeezed in one corner

Comment: Thats weird.. your output should be all the table rows. Can you `console.log(data)` in your ajax result and provide me with the results?

Comment: May i  know how to do the "console.log(data)"

Comment: place it right before this line `$("#comment").html(data);` then check your browser's console. If you are using chrome, right click and choose "inspect element" then click on the Console tab

Comment: this is what i saw on chrome, </body>
</html><tr><td>1234</td><td>5678</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1200</td><td>1500</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td></td></tr><td></td></tr>

Comment: looks ok, except that I dont get where you are getting `</body> </html>` from, you should only be getting the `<tr>`s. Are you getting this from the CONSOLE tab?

Comment: do you have Teamviewer? if so provide me with you ID and passcode, and I can help you remotely

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly define dataType that you expect from a server:

```
dataType: "html"
```

And the code would be:

```
function showComment() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "registerarray.php",
        data: "action=showcomment",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#comment").html(data);
        }
});
```